# Parse json with null fields

Tags: json, parsing, go

How parse data from json without field? Omitempty not working.

Need to get int 1234 and other data (id, owner)

```
{"response":[1234,{"id":1,"owner":3},{"id":3,"owner":5}]}
```

Code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type SectionDB_Exam_Add struct {
    id          int         `json:"id"`
    Owner           int         `json:"owner"`
}

type CreateExamType struct {
    Response []SectionDB_Exam_Add
}

var tests = `{"response":[{"id":1,"owner":3},{"id":3,"owner":5}]}`
var how_parse_this = `{"response":[1234,{"id":1,"owner":3},{"id":3,"owner":5}]}`

func main() {

    var var_CreateExamType = &CreateExamType{}

    var b_Data = []byte(tests)
    //var b_Data = []byte(how_parse_this)       // How parse 1234 and other data?

    json.Unmarshal(b_Data, var_CreateExamType)

    for _, mt := range var_CreateExamType.Response {
              fmt.Println(mt.Owner)
        }

}
```

Playground:
http://play.golang.org/p/NwGrrbTh-e

Comment: Nope. In other question they doing "foreach" from json.

Comment: The other questions are somewhat different, yes, but the same rules apply in your case. Use `[]interface{}` to unmarshal results generally and make assertions later. If you know for sure that the data structure is consistent, you can write your own unmarshaller by implementing func (*RawMessage) UnmarshalJSON: http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage. Then you can decode the raw message into different structs as needed. Just be aware that doing this can get very messy if the incoming json isn't consistent (e.g. always a number followed by an object).